# how to get browser URL to show values of a collection_select category - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

Hi I am using the collection_select function when doing an advanced search on my site.

I want the browser url to show the names of the categories that are options.

So I doing:

```
<%= collection_select(:company, :country_id, @country, :id, :name, {:prompt => true, :class=>"bbFormSelect"}, :name => "country_name") %>
```

my browser url shows something like

```
&country_name=5B
```

Can I get it to display the country?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
document.location = document.location + '?country_name=' + document.getElementById('yourselectid');
```

hope it helps